# AWS CLI step-functions to get failed executions

Tags: aws-cli, aws-step-functions

How to write a query using AWS CLI (terminal) for step functions to get all Failed executions from past 3 days & store the result in csv file?

This command is returning all failed records since 3 months but i need only from past 3 days

> aws stepfunctions list-executions --state-machine-arn "ARN" --status-filter "FAILED" --region "eu-west-1"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `list-executions` allow you to define a `--start-time` parameter like some other APIs do.

But what you can do is set `--max-items` which will limit the number of items your are returned. You can also enhance your request by using `--no-paginate` and handling the pagination manually only searching for the next page of results if it has not already surpassed day 3.

Answer (score 0):

list-executions has no parameters to filter the date range from executions logs.
Until there is a feature to do so, it expects us to query the JSON response ourselves.

Did you try using a JS script like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < executions.length; i++)
{
  if(executions[i].execution.<startDate OR endDate> == '<your condition>')
  {
    return executions[i].execution;
  }
}
```

If this works for you, then you can load this response to the csv you need.
To convert it to csv, I use [Dasel](https://github.com/TomWright/dasel)